# Change XML tag name

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I want to transform an XML document which I have parsed with `XmlSlurper`. The (identical) XML tag names should be replaced with the value of the `id` attribute; all other attributes should be dropped. Starting from this code:

```
def xml = """<tag id="root">
            |  <tag id="foo" other="blah" more="meh">
            |    <tag id="bar" other="huh"/>
            |  </tag>
            |</tag>""".stripMargin()

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

// Some magic here.

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(root)
```

I want to get the following:

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar/>
  </foo>
</root>
```

(I write test assertions on the XML, and want to simplify the structure for them.) I've read [Updating XML with XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Updating+XML+with+XmlSlurper) and searched around, but found no way with `replaceNode()` or `replaceBody()` to exchange a node while keeping its children.

Comment: I assume some tags also have content? If not, you can do: `root.breadthFirst().each { n -> n.replaceNode { "${n.@id}"( n.children() ) } }` But this will lose any content in the nodes

Comment: @tim_yates: Currently, there's no content, so your solution (though incomplete) would already work for me. Please post it as an answer!

Comment: done :-) I'll have a think about a more generalised recursive function

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; I'm anxious to see a general solution.

Comment: Added what seems -- after a quick test -- a more general solution

Comment: Great. The biggest drawback I see is that one ends up with a String, not a `GPathResult`, so if there's further processing (and not just printing like in this toy example), it would have to be re-parsed again.

Comment: True, but I don't believe it's possible using `XmlSlurper`'s data structure, and `XmlParser` doesn't let you replace the root node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the 'magic' in to the code in the question gives:

```
def xml = """<tag id="root">
            |  <tag id="foo" other="blah" more="meh">
            |    <tag id="bar" other="huh"/>
            |  </tag>
            |</tag>""".stripMargin()

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

root.breadthFirst().each { n ->
  n.replaceNode { 
    "${n.@id}"( n.children() )
  }
}

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(root)
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <foo>
    <bar/>
  </foo>
</root>
```

HOWEVER, this will drop any content in the nodes. To maintain content, we would probably need to use recursion and XmlParser to generate a new doc from the existing one... I'll have a think

#### More general solution

I think this is more generalised:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def xml = """<tag id="root">
            |  <tag id="foo" other="blah" more="meh">
            |    <tag id="bar" other="huh">
            |      something
            |    </tag>
            |    <tag id="bar" other="huh">
            |      something else
            |    </tag>
            |    <noid>woo</noid>
            |  </tag>
            |</tag>""".stripMargin()

def root = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

def munge( builder, node ) {
  if( node instanceof Node && node.children() ) {
    builder."${node.@id ?: node.name()}" {
      node.children().each {
        munge( builder, it )
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    if( node instanceof Node ) {
      "${node.@id ?: node.name()}"()
    }
    else {
      builder.mkp.yield node
    }
  }
}

def w = new StringWriter()
def builder = new MarkupBuilder( w )
munge( builder, root )

println XmlUtil.serialize( w.toString() )
```

And prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <foo>
    <bar>something</bar>
    <bar>something else</bar>
    <noid>woo</noid>
  </foo>
</root>
```

Now passes through nodes with no (or empty) `id` attributes